# Systemd to ExecStart always executing?

Tags: debian, systemd, luks

Working on creating a systemD service to retrieve a key file from a remote SSH server and then use it to auto mount an encrypted Luks disk on a server(not the root drive).

```
[Unit]
Description=Open encrypted data volume
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
StopWhenUnneeded=true

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/etc/luks/key.sh | /sbin/cryptsetup -d - -v luksOpen /dev/disk/by-uuid/13b051b5-7f4f-4030-92da-d59f12422f40 Data_Crypt'
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/sbin/cryptsetup -d - -v luksClose Data_Crypt
```

This appears to work correctly, however every time I run

```
systemctl start unlock-data.service
```

I check the systemd logs and I can see it both unlocked the drive and then locked it.  Both ExectStart and ExecStop are firing.  If I completely remove the ExecStop line from it and run "systemctl start" again, it unlocks the drive exactly as expected.

I've also tried chaning the type to "simple" but that didn't work either.   I believe oneshot is correct for what I'm doing.

This is on Debian 11.3.  Fresh install today.

Why is ExecStop firing every time this starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour is mostly likely due to the `StopWhenUnneeded=true` setting in the unit section. As per the [manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.unit.5.html), the definition of unneeded is this:

> `StopWhenUnneeded=`
>
> Takes a boolean argument. If true, this unit will be stopped when it
> is no longer used. Note that, in order to minimize the work to be
> executed, systemd will not stop units by default unless they are
> conflicting with other units, or the user explicitly requested their
> shut down. **If this option is set, a unit will be automatically
> cleaned up if no other active unit requires it**. Defaults to false.

Since no other unit depends on this custom unit, systemd would stop it as soon as it starts.

Comment: It might be a better idea to make it a dependency of mounting the data partition, that way the dependency resolver actually does something useful.

Comment: It might be an even better idea to make it cooperate with the existing systemd-cryptsetup@ units instead of doing everything by hand.

Comment: That did it, thank you!

Comment: Also, to the comment on systemd-cryptsetup@.  Looked at that and it doesn't appear to work for my setup, or atleast the docs don't make it appear that way.